# How to convert dropdown to radio using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listbox, radio-button

I have a drop down select and I want to change it to radio button:

**HTML**

```
<select id="designation" title="Designation" name="designation">
    <option value="">Choose Option..</option>
    <option value="1">Educator</option>
    <option value="2">Student Subscriber</option>
    <option value="3">Adult Subscriber</option>
</select>
<div id="r"></div>
```

I try to add this code but is display only the buttons without labels, how I can add labels too?

**Jquery**

```
jQuery("#designation option").each(function(i, e) {
    jQuery("<input type='radio' name='r' />")
        .attr("value", jQuery(this).val())
        .attr("checked", i == 0)
        .click(function () {
            jQuery("#designation").val(jQuery(this).val());
        })
        .appendTo("#r");
});
```

Comment: radio labels  are extra html. you never provide that extra html. e.g. `<input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar"> Bar` - putting in `Bar` is up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create it separately,

```
jQuery("#designation option").each(function(i, e) {
  (jQuery("<input type='radio' name='r' />")
    .attr("value", jQuery(this).val())
    .attr("checked", i == 0)
    .click(function() {
      jQuery("#designation").val(jQuery(this).val());
    }).add($("<label>"+ this.textContent +"</label>")))
    .appendTo("#r");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/twmwch8o/)

Comment: Thank you but instead of 4 radios now I have 8

Comment: @RobertD Are you calling this code again and again? Because it is working fine for me in the attached demo

Comment: only one time I don't know why is happen this

Comment: @RobertD Can you reproduce that in a fiddle? So that we could fix it.

Comment: I can;t is a magento platform

Comment: @RobertD Do one thing, set a break point over this code and during the second hit over the break point, check the `callStack`, It will give you the reason why it is getting called for the second time..

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/twmwch8o/1/)

```
$('#designation option').each(function() {
var label = $(this).html();
var value = $(this).attr('value');
if(value != ""){ // Here it will remove empty values
$('#r').append('<td><input type="radio"  name="r" value="'+value+'">'+label+'</td>');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add label and remove the choose option radio

Also use `.remove()` to remove the dropdown after creating radio input.

```
jQuery("#designation option").each(function(i, e) {
  if(i != 0) {
  (jQuery("<input type='radio' name='r' />")
    .attr("value", jQuery(this).val())
    .attr("checked", i == 1)
    .click(function() {
      jQuery("#designation").val(jQuery(this).val());
    }).add($("<label>"+ this.textContent +"</label>")))
    .appendTo("#r");

  }

});
jQuery("#designation").remove();
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/twmwch8o/3/)